# How to compare current string is same as given n number of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, string-comparison

I've String "America" I want to compare this string with available string i.e

```
"Depot Meridian - Turkey","IMP Logistics - Ukraine","Cryosite Depot - Australia","Thermo Fisher Scientific - Colombia","Fisher Singapore - Singapore","Fisher - Brazil - Brazil","Fisher Russia - Russia","Depot Meridian - Turkey","IMP Logistics - Ukraine","Cryosite Depot - Australia","Thermo Fisher Scientific - Colombia","Fisher Singapore - Singapore","Fisher - Brazil - Brazil","Fisher Russia - Russia"
```

Here each string is separated by `,` So I want return true if string "America" is equal to the given string how can I do this in javascript?

Comment: store the strings in array and then use `arr.some((str) => str.includes(word));`

Comment: Each string is separated by `,` ... sure, but where are those strings?

Comment: Nothing React specific here - also do you want to get a positive for "Bla bla - America" or just "America" is in the list?

Comment: so this is a string with double quotes inside and commas?

Comment: Is this snippet an array of strings or a single string?

Comment: there is multiple string seperated by comma, I want America should comapre with each string which is seperated by comma and if it's true return true

Comment: No it's not single string

Comment: What does _"there is multiple string seperated by comma"_ mean? How do you separate multiple strings by comma in JavaScript? Is this an array of strings? Are these different variables? Is this one string/text/file that you want to split into multiple strings? Could you provide a JavaScript code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove double quotes, then split with `,` and use the `includes` method to search inside array.

```js
let string = '"Depot Meridian - Turkey","IMP Logistics - Ukraine","Cryosite Depot - Australia","Thermo Fisher Scientific - Colombia","Fisher Singapore - Singapore","Fisher - Brazil - Brazil","Fisher Russia - Russia","Depot Meridian - Turkey","IMP Logistics - Ukraine","Cryosite Depot - Australia","Thermo Fisher Scientific - Colombia","Fisher Singapore - Singapore","Fisher - Brazil - Brazil","Fisher Russia - Russia"'

let arr = string.replaceAll('"', '').split(',')

console.log(arr.includes('America'));
console.log(arr.includes('Thermo Fisher Scientific - Colombia'));
```